# Convert text column into time format column and calculate the sum

Tags: date, time, powerbi, dax

I have a one time column in format 00:01:30 (HH:MM:SS). This column is a text format column.
this text column format convert to a time format column and create a new measure for the total time sum.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily convert your Text column into Time using

```
Time = TIMEVALUE('Table'[Text])
```

But the problem is that the Time format doesn't support more than 24 hours, so your SUM will potentially lead to an overflow. Here's a workaround:

1. Create a calculated "Seconds" **Column**

```
Seconds = 
VAR Time = 
    TIMEVALUE('Table'[Text])
RETURN
    HOUR(Time) * 3600 + MINUTE(Time) * 60 + SECOND(Time)
```

2. Aggregate the Seconds with this **Measure** and convert back to a "Duration-like" format:

```
Total Duration = 
VAR total_seconds = 
    SUM('Table'[Seconds])
VAR days = 
    QUOTIENT(total_seconds, 24 * 60 *60)
VAR rest1 = 
    MOD(total_seconds, 24 * 60 * 60)
VAR hours = 
    QUOTIENT(rest1, 60 * 60)
VAR rest2 = 
    MOD(total_seconds, 60 * 60)
VAR minutes = 
    QUOTIENT(rest2, 60)
VAR seconds = 
    MOD(rest2, 60)
RETURN
    days & "." & FORMAT(hours, "0#") & ":" & FORMAT(minutes, "0#") & ":" & FORMAT(seconds, "0#")
```

[image]